# Multiple hyperlinks on a image in pdf android

Tags: android, pdf, itext, pdf-generation

I created an app that generates business card with ( **Phone**, **Email**, **Link** )

Saves it in two formats   **PDF** (using LIB  [itextpdf](https://github.com/itext/itextpdf)) and **Image**

I inserted the same **Image** inside **PDF**

**Image looks like this**

[image]

**Now problem is**

`Number`, `email` and `website` should be clickable

**What I tried so far**

I tried to hack this feature using `Hyperlink Rectangle`

But when I add Rectangle using the following code

```
PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(36, 636, 559, 10);
                rect.setBorder(Rectangle.BOX);
                rect.setBorderWidth(2);
                canvas.rectangle(rect);
```

***But i am unable to place the rectangle in right place***

X, Y, width AND height is ok but gave this output

**PDF OUTPUT**

[image]

**My questions are**

1. Is it possible to hack this feature?
2. How to make Clickable Rectangle that is positioned correctly?
3. Any other way you can suggest me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I solved my problem and answering my own question*

**Solved my Rectangle position with**

```
Rectangle phone = new Rectangle(36, 640,540,676);
Rectangle email = new Rectangle(36,604,540, 640);
Rectangle website = new Rectangle(36,568,540, 604);
```

**Linked the Rectangle with following code**

```
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(file.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "card1_" + name.getText().toString() + ".pdf");
                PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(file.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "card1_Clickable_" + name.getText().toString() + ".pdf"));
                Rectangle phone = new Rectangle(36, 640,540,676);
                Rectangle email = new Rectangle(36,604,540, 640);
                Rectangle website = new Rectangle(36,568,540, 604);
                phone.setBorder(0);
                email.setBorder(0);
                website.setBorder(0);

                PdfAnnotation link = PdfAnnotation.createLink(stamper.getWriter(),
                        phone, PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_INVERT,new PdfAction("tel://"+phone_edit.getText().toString()));
                link.setBorder(new PdfBorderArray(0, 0, 0));

                PdfAnnotation link1 = PdfAnnotation.createLink(stamper.getWriter(),
                        email, PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_INVERT,new PdfAction("mailto:"+email_edit.getText().toString()));
                link1.setBorder(new PdfBorderArray(0, 0, 0));

                PdfAnnotation link2 = PdfAnnotation.createLink(stamper.getWriter(),
                        website, PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_INVERT,new PdfAction(website_edit.getText().toString()));
                link2.setBorder(new PdfBorderArray(0, 0, 0));

                stamper.addAnnotation(link,1);
                stamper.addAnnotation(link1,1);
                stamper.addAnnotation(link2,1);
                stamper.close();
```

Now i am able to click every link on image